# Perl for web development

Tags: perl

How I can run Perl script from a web browser? Is there a need for some kind of web server (i.e. as we use Apache for PHP)?

Comment: Check this modern Perl framework for web-development: [Mojolicous](http://mojolicio.us/).
Mojolicous is easy, flexible and modern!

Comment: Take a look at [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/), [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/), or [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/).

Comment: I can't comment on tutorials point, but [keep away from tizag](http://perl-tutorial.org/rejected/tizag/). Hmm, looks like tutorials point is, at least in part [to be avoided](http://perl-tutorial.org/rejected/) too.

Comment: If you want a good tutorial then start at http://learn.perl.org/ or http://perl-tutorial.org/#index1h1

Answer (score 4):

> Now I want to know how I can run perl script on browser.

It certainly used to be possible to run client side PerlScript.

… providing the user had the ActiveState PerlScript plugin installed

… and was running Internet Explorer.

I've no idea if that is still available, but it isn't in common use on the WWW so would only be practical for system that you control (such as an Intranet application). Even then, the Internet Explorer lock in makes it a bad idea.

> Is there need any kind of web server as we use in Apache for PHP.

Server side Perl is the usual choice for the WWW, and that needs a webserver

All of the recent development I've seen (baring quick, hacky demos written in CGI), uses [Plack / PGSI](http://plackperl.org/). This defines an common interface between a Perl program and a number of means to interact with web servers (including CGI, FastCGI, mod_perl and mod_psgi). It also provides a `plackup` as a tiny webserver for testing and debugging.

It is used by most of the current crop of web frameworks for Perl

- [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/)
- [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/)
- [Web::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/Web%3a%3aSimple)
- etc

Here is a very simple skeleton application I knocked together while figuring out PSGI. It just sends details of the request back to the browser.

```
use v5.12;
use Data::Dump qw/dump/;
use Plack::Request;

my $app = sub {
        my $env = shift;
        my $req = Plack::Request->new($env);
        my $content = dump($req->parameters);

        return [ 
                200,
                [ "Content-Type" => "text/plain" ],
                [ $content ]
        ];
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Add in your DocumentRoot (or only in the folder where you want to execute perl script) a file called `.htaccess` with the following content:

```
Options -Indexes +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .pl
```

From now on, everyfile that has as extension `.pl` will be executed on the server side before sending the output to the client.

Your file has to begin with the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), otherwise the server will not know how to interpret its content:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# And then your code...

use strict;
use warnings;

...
...
```

This is what you basically needs to run perl script as you actually run php script. Of course, you need an http server (Apache is always a good choice).

Of course, if you're looking for a development framework that makes your life easier, have a look to other answers. However, none of them is required to run perl on a web server and they are almost useless if you want to run only small script.

Comment: And don't forget to print the content type, so you don't get a 500 error, eg: `print "content-type: text/plain\r\n\r\n";`

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a huge topic.  Not sure where to recommend that you start.

I think you mean wanting to run the perl script in the web server, not in the browser (such a thing is not supported by default and I don't know of any browser plugins that do this off-hand).  For a web server, probably the best thing to do is to either pick up a framework (Catalyst, Dancer etc) or write a few CGI scripts (see CGI::Simple on CPAN and its documentation for a good place to start there).

Additionally, there is Plack and Mojolicious for web service frameworks.  These can connect to Apache and other servers, and can cache code.  Keep in mind that caching code if your variables are not well scoped can result in interesting side effects.

Comment: Article is not bad but missing some links to easy navigate to